# SQL Server: add incremental value (not identity)

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a table and I want to insert some rows. There is a column `num` which is not identity. When the insertion of new rows takes place I want the `num` value to be incremented by 1 starting from the highest existing value. Here is my code until now:

```
insert into table1 ( num, val)
select (( select max(num) from table1) + row_number() over (order by num)), val
from table1
```

Here is the error I get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

**UPDATE**
The error comes from the trigger so I posted a new question regarding the trigger: 
[SQL Server 2012 trigger: Doesnt work with multiple rows inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606525/sql-server-2012-trigger-doesnt-work-with-multiple-rows-inserted)

Comment: Your query cannot return that error.  The only subquery is an aggregation query with no `group by` -- and that returns exactly one row.  In addition, you should be using a window function to calculate the max.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - there may be a trigger on `table1` generating this error in *response* to the above query. Of course, we can't help track the error further without seeing the trigger also.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed... there is a trigger. And I think the problem is that the query I want to create inserts multiple lines at once. But in the trigger;s code expects 1 row everytime. Triggers keeps track of the changes in Table1

Comment: @aggicd . . . Ask another question about fixing the trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is it possible instead of altering the trigger alter this code so it inserts one row a time?

Comment: @aggicd - that's exactly the wrong direction to look to fix things. Triggers *should* be written to cope with multi-row inserts, deletes, updates. Because even if you "fix" your current statement above, you're leaving a trip-wire waiting to catch the next person who writes a statement involving this table where they happen to affect multiple rows. (Often, the "next person" is yourself after 6 months/enough time has elapsed that you forget about the trigger's strangeness)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I asked this because I would like to test if thats the case and the mistake is the assumption of the code's trigger that each change will be row by row instead of multiple rows in the same time

Answer (score 0):

You should be using window functions instead of a subquery:

```
insert into table1 (num, val)
    select ( max(num) over () + row_number() over (order by num) ), val
    from table1;
```

However, the query in your question cannot return that error, because an aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.

Comment: By the way if I use this code I get error about inserting duplicate key in table1

Comment: @aggicd . . . That does not seem possible, unless you have a `where` clause.